# How SQL Server detect program name in sys.dm_exec_sessions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone explain the how below mentioned query detect program_name 
eg: **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**,**Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query** etc..

```
select login_name,program_name,host_name,nt_domain,nt_user_name from sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

Comment: The application passes that value when it connects to the server.

Comment: if I create my own application and want to connect it with SQL with its own application name which will be maintained in SQL session. Actually I am just wondering if I connect ms excel or any other application with sql it detects application name,and it is not automatically getting done. there must be a parameter to pass.

Comment: I just know how to do that using Java/JDBC. But other programming languages should have similar features.

Comment: Ok. can you please share the code. I want to implement this in C# but java code may help.

Comment: I just pass connection properties as documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server detect program name from [connection string property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can change your program name of your SSMS by used following step.

[image: Step 1]

[image]

After connect to your database you can get following query :

```
Select login_name,
       program_name,
       host_name,
       nt_domain,
       nt_user_name 
From sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

You can also use connection string parameter from your application.